# Put a link on a specific One2many object and call a Python function

Tags: javascript, function, odoo, odoo-8

I have to do a function link like **Add an Item** in One2Many records in OdooV8. Here's my JavaScript code:

```
openerp.my_module = function (instance) {
instance.web.form.One2ManyList.include({
    pad_table_to: function (count){
        var self = this;
        var res = this._super(count);
        this.$current.find('.oe_form_field_one2many_list_row_add').append(
            $('<a>', {href: '#'}).text(_t("    Add in Configuration"))
                .mousedown(function () {
                    if (self.view.editor.is_editing()) {
                        self.view.__ignore_blur = true;
                    }
                })
                .click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    if (self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout) {
                        clearTimeout(self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout);
                        self.view.editor.form.__blur_timeout = false;
                    }
                    self.view.ensure_saved().done(function () {
                        //run your js code here
                    });
                })
            );
        }
})
```

};

Here's the result in Purchase Order Line:

[Purchase Order Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dTNL.png)

Now my problems are:

> 1. I want to put the link in a specific One2Many object only, because it appears in all One2Many views. For example, only in Purchase Order Line.
> 2. I want to call a python function. Once the **Add in Configuration** is clicked, it should call a function that returns a pop up form. How
>      to do this in JavaScript?

I'm still not familiar with JavaScript and someone help me to do the first part. Kindly help me if you have an idea how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set condition for certain models

```
//Example
var models = ['your.model1', 'your.model2']; // Array of your models
if(models.includes(this.dataset.model)){
            // Your code
}
```

This will appear only in that models.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JavaScript Sir, how can I put the link only to the declared models?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Widget. That way you can use it to control which widget to use on your One2many's.

```
<field name="my_one_too_many" widget="special_o2m_with_configuration"/>
```

To open a pop up form, you have to call an action from client with its target set as `new`. An action like this. Or call directly the action by its ID if you have it in the database.

```
    {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'target': 'new',
        'res_model': 'some.model',
        'res_id': some_id  # Or no ID if you want a new record
    }
```

Comment: Is the widget="special_o2m_with_configuration" is a custom widget?

Comment: Yes, it's "your" custom widget. The widget that you would have created.